# The issue about call by reference in Java

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

i know that java is call by reference,
i have a question about these code

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[]  argv){


    ArrayList<Integer>  a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int aa = 5;
    int[] aaa ={0,1,2};
    a.add(1);
    aaa[0]=999;
    System.out.println("ArrayList "+ a.toString());
    System.out.println("int "+ aa);
    System.out.println("Array "+ Arrays.toString(aaa));

    add2(a,aa,aaa);


    System.out.println("ArrayList"+ a.toString());
    System.out.println("int "+ aa);
    System.out.println("Array "+ Arrays.toString(aaa));
}

private static  void add2(ArrayList<Integer> a1,int aa1,int[] aaa1)
{
    a1.add(2);
    aa1=aa1+10;
    aaa1[2]=999;
}
```

**the result is**

```
ArrayList: [1]

int:       5

Array:     [999, 1, 2]

ArrayList: [1, 2]

int:       5

Array:     [999, 1, 999]
```

why `ArrayList`  and `Array` will change when i call function
and "int" won't change

Can someone explain to me these situation  , thanks a lot

Comment: [No, java is call by value, always.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference?rq=1).

Comment: **No.**  Java is call by value..

Comment: What result were you expecting?

Comment: See here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 1):

You are partially right about Java being pass-by-reference (well [not really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference#40523), but that's a different topic); however, this is only true when passing objects.

According to [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html):

> Primitive arguments, such as an int or a double, are passed into methods by value. This means that any changes to the values of the parameters exist only within the scope of the method. When the method returns, the parameters are gone and any changes to them are lost.

As the quote states, primitive types (like `int`) are passed to the function by value. A copy of the primitive is given to the function when it is called, and thus any changes made by the function have no effect on the original data.